# what does "+3" represents in [:index+3] in python?

Tags: python

Here is the problem statement:

```
return list[index:]+list[:index+3]
```

I know [:] represents all the elements of the list. 
what does this "+3" represents here?

Comment: `index` is a particular position in your list. `index+3` is a position 3 places later.

Comment: See [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: To dive more into the details: It means `index.__add__(3)`. The result is trivial if `index` is an integer and can be pretty much everything if `index` is an other type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: The meaning of `some_int + 3` inside the square brackets is exactly the same as outside the square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

for this line:

```
list[:index+3]
```

if index is set to 1, it is the same as

```
list[:4]
```

it's a simple sum on a variable, meaning it will read to 3 positions after your index variable

Comment: Please give the credit where credit is due and accept this as your answer if so

Answer (score 1):

Every element from `[index]` till the end plus every element from beginning up to (but not including) `[index+3]`
Let's have a look at an example:

```
>>> list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 
>>> index=2
>>> list[index:]+list[:index+3]
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Here `index` is `2`, thus `list[index:]+list[:index+3]` is exactly the same as `list[index:]+list[0:2+3]` which is `list[index:]+list[0:5]`. So, Every element from `[2]` till the end plus every element from beginning up to (but not including) `[5]`